# Change the filename format of saved featured images

Tags: php, uploads, images

Does anyone know how I could change the way wordpress saves the featured image's additional image sizes?

Right now I have the main image saving like so:

```
test_builder_banner_2.jpg
```

and for each additional image size it saves like so:

```
test_builder_banner-610x260.jpg
```

All I want to do is get rid of the "-" between the name of the file and the file size, and replace it with an underscore.

Is there a filter I can use or something of that sort?

Answer (score 3):

There is a filter to use for the array containing the filename that is saved to postmeta but since there are no filters available to change the filename before it is saved you have to manually change it using [`rename()`](https://www.php.net/rename).

```
function wpse_filter_image_resize_name( $filename ) {
    $new_name = preg_replace( "/-(?<match>\\d)/ui", "_$1", $filename );

    if ( rename( $filename, $new_name ) )
        return $new_name;

    return $filename;
}
add_filter( 'image_make_intermediate_size', 'wpse_filter_image_resize_name' );
```